# str_replace encoding issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, utf-8

I'm writing a str_replace function to replace specific combinations of special characters and numbers with a span and a color-style tag. For instance, `` `5 `` gets replaced with a `<span style='color=0000FF'>`. The values that have to be replaced and the replacers are selected from a SQL (MySQL) table encoded in UTF-8-ci to support special chars and umlauts.

```
$output=str_replace("{$farben['anzeigecode']}","<span style='color: {$farben['htmlfarbe']}'>",$output);
```

The function is handling things such as `` `z `` and `+1` just fine, replacing them with a `<span color=x>` tag. It also, as expected, leaves umlauts and special chars untouched if they don't have a `` ` `` or `+` in front of the letter.

Where it messes things up and returns the html expression (`&uml;` for instance) is combinations such as: `` `ö `` `` `ü `` `` `Ü ``, etc. It also ignores (but doesn't return the html expression) combinations consisting of `+` or `#` and a umlaut, e.g. `+ö`, `+Ö`, `+ä` - even though these are present in the SQL table the function is working with.

The file where the function is in and the files where it is being used are saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

Tl;dr: This is really puzzling for me - in the end, the output of a Ü that the function doesn't touch works fine, but `` `Ü `` where the function is supposed to replace something returns `&Uuml;` and `+Ü` and `#Ü` are just ignored.

What could be causing this?

Comment: is connection also set to UTF-8?

Comment: This function should not return *HTML entities* (&Uuml;) at all. Are you sure your *input* isn't already HTML-encoded? If in doubt, always use `echo bin2hex($str)` to see how the characters are *actually* encoded, then figure out where the byte representation differs; that's the only reason `str_replace` would not replace a str: because it's not the same string.

Comment: I've set the connection with$sql = "SELECT nummer,anzeigecode,htmlfarbe FROM arceia_farben USING utf8"; and further $output = mb_convert_encoding($output,"HTML-ENTITIES", "utf8"); just to be on the safe side. Thanks for fixing up my question, deceze, and I'll see if I can find out more with bin2hex and report back here. Might take me a bit though - thanks to the two of you!